# Getting identity auto-number from SQL in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've been messing with an Access unbound form with SQL back-end. I add a new record using VBA but want to retrieve the Identity value created. At first I simply tried "tbField0 = rs.fields(0).value" but after the rs.update is shows  record is deleted. I tried adding rs.bookmark = rs.lastmodified but same result.

Found this article 
[Access: Get newly created auto number in DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839377/access-get-newly-created-auto-number-in-dao) and a comment by Rick about BIGINT & Access which I knew about. I don't use BIGINT because of it but NUMERIC instead. So, since no suggestions would work I tried to change the field type to INT and test. Works as required.

Therefore my question is how can I retrieve an incremented identity field from SQL which is not a datatype if INT using VBA in Access. I saw some mention of an OUTPUT command but not sure how to use or if applicable.

---

I have created two tables, one called tbl1_Int and the other tbl2_Num. Both contain two fields IndexID and Field1. Both Field1 are nchar and as you might surmise IndexID is a Int in tbl1_Int and a Numeric in tbl2_Num.

Created a blank form with two unbound fields txtIndex and txtField1 as well as two buttons btnInt and btnNumeric with the following code.

```
Private Sub btnInt_Click()

    Dim DB As Database
    Dim RS As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo_tbl1_Int (Field1) VALUES ('" & txtField1 & "')"

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    DB.Execute strSQL

    txtIndex = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
    DB.Close

End Sub

Private Sub btnNumeric_Click()

    Dim DB As Database
    Dim RS As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo_tbl2_Num (Field1) VALUES ('" & txtField1 & "')"

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    DB.Execute strSQL

    txtIndex = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
    DB.Close

End Sub
```

The records get created in the tables however it will only capture (thus populate) the index from tbl1 which is when the identity is a field type of Int. Which leads back to my original question of how do I capture the index when it is not an Integer?

---

I've gotten it to work with the following.

```
Private Sub btnNumeric_Click()

    Dim DB As Database
    Dim RS As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "select * from dbo_tbl2_Num where false"

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    RS.AddNew
    RS.Fields(1) = txtField1
    RS.Update
    RS.Move 0, RS.LastModified

    txtIndex = Null
    txtIndex = RS.Fields(0).Value
    RS.Close
    DB.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Just use the query `SELECT @@IDENTITY;` after your insert. Note that `@@IDENTITY` is scoped to the connection, so don't close and reopen it before calling it.

Comment: Comintern: It took me a while to reply but I have tried the @@Identity but it only works with a field type of Int. I will reply with more detail.